# Summing a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

$\text{Determine the sum of the Fourier series of $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$  all |x| $\leq$ $\pi$}$

I found that the Fourier series was:

$$1-\frac{1}{2}\cos(x)+2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-1}\cos(nx)$$

Do I just take the average of the right and left endpoints? $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ is both convergent on $[-\pi,\pi]%$ so I would just think I average $f(x)$ at the endpoints.

That gives me a sum of $0$ though. I'm not sure if that's right...

Comment: What is a "sum of a Fourier series"? What is $F$? Why do you consider $f'$?

Comment: The Fourier series is the sum of those cosines. The function you get when summing them up.

Comment: What do you mean by that @mathreadler?

Comment: It is difficult to interpret your question.

Comment: Here is the original question without any changes:

$\text{Find the Fourier series of $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and determine its sum for all |x| $\leq$ $\pi$}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $2\pi$-periodic function $f$, which restriction to $[-\pi,\pi]$ is $x \mapsto x \sin x$ is continuous. Also, it has right and left derivatives everywhere. Thus, the Dirichlet conditions are satisfied. The Fourier series of $f$ converges pointwise towards $f$, i.e. for all $x$,
$$ a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos (nx) + b_n \sin (nx) = f (x) \, , $$
where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f$. In particular, this equality holds on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: What would be the sum though? It would just be the function itself? That seems really strange.

Comment: That's it. Here, the Fourier series (when summing up an infinity of terms) is the function itself.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you.